# Programmatically export a SharePoint Online list Daily

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-workflow, powershell-ise

I've been doing SharePoint for a few years now and this seemingly simple task has me stumped. I would like to automate the export of a list so that it runs at the end of each day and emails the report to me. This is in O365 so I can't just plop some PowerShell on the server, call it from bat file in Task Scheduler and be done.

I've seen people mention building out .aspx pages and use Javascript/REST to generate the report, which is fine, but I don't know how to then automatically email that off each day.

I've played around with SharePoint Online Management Shell but don't know how to pull the list data in.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: You can easily do this via CSOM using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and running it on a host inside your organization.  I usually do this via C# but it works in PowerShell just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this via CSOM using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client and running it on a host inside your organization.  I usually do this via C# but it works in PowerShell just fine, I borrowed the metacode from: http://sharepointryan.com/2014/03/07/return-splistitems-using-csom-and-powershell-without-writing-caml/

```
$GLOBAL:Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("http://Your.O365Url")
$GLOBAL:Credentials = Get-Credential -UserName $EmailAddress -Message "Office 365 Password"
$Context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Credentials.UserName,$Credentials.Password)
$GLOBAL:Web = $GLOBAL:Context.Web
$GLOBAL:Context.Load($GLOBAL:Web)
$GLOBAL:Context.ExecuteQuery()

$list = $GLOBAL:Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListOfItems")
$items = $list.GetItems()
$GLOBAL:Context.Load($items)
$GLOBAL:Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

CSOM works from anywhere as long as you have the libraries installed.

Comment: Thank you Arcan! That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Happy to help.  CSOM is a lifesaver.